# SAGEMATH: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: syntax-error, substitution, sage

At the end I wanted to substitute `qij^2=qij`, `i,j=1,2,3,4`
and got the error:

```py
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

The code:

```py
sage: f1 = 2*x1 + x2 + 1
sage: f2 = -x1 + 5*x2 - 2
sage: e1 = expand(f1^2)
sage: e2 = expand(f2^2)
sage: var('q11, q12, q13, q14, q21, q22, q23, q24')
(q11, q12, q13, q14, q21, q22, q23, q24)
sage: E1 = e1.substitute(x1=q11+(2q12)-q13-(2q14), x2=q21+(2q22)-q23-(2q24))
sage: E2 = e2.substitute(x1=q11+(2q12)-q13-(2q14), x2=q21+(2q22)-q23-(2q24))
sage: E1a = expand(E1)
sage: E2a = expand(E2)
sage: E1aa = E1a.substitute(q11^2=q11, q12^2=q12, q13^2=q13, q14^2=q14,
....:                       q21^2=q21, q22^2=q22, q23^2=q23, q24^2=q24)
sage: E2aa = E2a.substitute(q11^2=q11, q12^2=q12, q13^2=q13, q14^2=q14,
....:                       q21^2=q21, q22^2=q22, q23^2=q23, q24^2=q24)
sage: E1aa, E2aa
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just substitute for a variable, you can use the `=` syntax: `E1a.substitute(q11=(whatever))`. If, though, you want to substitute for a more complicated expression, you need to use a different syntax:

```
E1a.substitute(q11^2=q1)    # will raise an error
E1a.substitute(q11^2==q1)   # should work
E1a.substitute({q11^2: q1}) # should work
```

The help message produced by `E1a.substitute?` gives some examples.